# Mutate multiple columns using loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a df like this :

```
Class_A  Class_B
   78       50
   40       60 
   30       70
```

The result I want is

```
Class_A  Class_B  RankClass_A  RankClass_B
   78       50       1            3
   40       60       2            2
   30       70       3            1
```

Basically, I can create two or more cols by using mutate function. However, when I put it in a loop to create more cols the code does not work.

Here is my code

```
label<-c('RankClass_A',"RankClass_B")
for (i in 1:2){
  for (k in 1:2){ 
    mutate(df,label[i]=dense_rank(desc(df[k])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not want to create all cols that are not relevant to the new data frame. Is there any way to select some cols by using mutate_all ?

Comment: `transform(df,rank = lapply(-df,rank))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `mutate_all` to create the 'Rank' columns

```
df %>% 
    mutate_all(funs(Rank = rank(-.)))
#    Class_A Class_B Class_A_Rank Class_B_Rank
#1      78      50            1            3
#2      40      60            2            2
#3      30      70            3            1
```

Comment: Maybe also add a base R option. `lapply(df, function(x) rank(-x))`